# How to restrict from adding to database before saving context object?

Tags: ios

`insertNewObjectForEntityForName` method inserts object to database for core data in iOS before saving the context .How to restrict it from adding to database before saving context object??

help in resolving this please.....

here is my code....
-(BOOL)addTeam:(Team *)team{

```
BOOL result = NO;
NSLog(@"inside dao %@ context obj %@",team.team_Name,context);
//here i am getting newly created object also before saving the context...
NSLog(@"Array of team before saving context :%@",[self getAllTeams]);
//  3
NSError *error;
if (![context save:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    result = NO;
}
NSLog(@"Team saved");
result = YES;
return result;
```

}

Comment: Are you assigning your object your create from insertNewObjectForEntityForName  method to to a persistent store?

Comment: Hello krishnan , i am creating object like this........         Team *teamz = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Team" inManagedObjectContext:context];                                      teamz.team_Name = _nameTextField.text;
teamz.short_Name = _shortNameTextField.text;  before saving context it is saving to database ...i don't know much about core data..

Comment: can you share the complete code regarding the DB operartion in your method?

Comment: ya sure here is my code //Method to add                                                  -(BOOL)addTeam:(Team *)team{                                    BOOL result = NO;Team *teamz = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectFor EntityForName: @"Team" inManagedObjectContext:context];                       teamz.team_Name=_nameTextField.text;  teamz.short_Name=_shortNameTextField.text;             //getAllTeams method is to view all records.            NSLog(@"Array of teams is :%@ ",[self getAllTeams]);} //here before context save the created object is adding to database ..

Comment: please put the code in the question and format it